# LDAP fails using port 389

Tags: active-directory, ldap, tls1.2

I just started using LDAP and noticed that even tho default port for TLS is 389 it will sometimes fail. I've done some research and found out that TLS can also use port 3268, tried this port and it works perfectly.What can be the problem using this port? Is it a known issue of Microsoft? Does anyone else experienced the same behavior?

Comment: The default LDAP/TLS port is 636 actually. You can get 389 to work if you've enabled STARTTLS at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

[StartTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS) would be done on port 389 or for the Global Catalog on port 3268.

LDAPS (SSL) would be performed on 636 or for the Global Catalog on port 3269.

I wonder if the servers you are accessing all support the functionality you are trying to perform.

Please provide more information.